# GCMRegistrar.isRegistered() vs GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId()

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

So if you take a look in google's demo app about gcm you gonna see that they made a registration check like following:

```
 final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    if (regId.equals("")) {
        // Automatically registers application on startup.
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
    } else {
        // Device is already registered on GCM, check server.
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
            ...
```

However [there is a method GCMRegistrar.isRegistered() does exist](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html#isRegistered%28android.content.Context%29). According to google's docs this method

> Checks whether the application was successfully registered on GCM
>   service.

So WHY didn't they use this method but they made a check if RegistrationId is empty? 
Now with this in mind I decided to use GCMRegistrar.isRegistered() instead of checking the regId for emptiness. So basicly my code looks like the following:

```
 final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    if (!GCMRegistrar.isRegistered(this)) {
        // Automatically registers application on startup.
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
    } else {
        // Device is already registered on GCM, check server.
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
            ...
```

But the most interesting part is the fact that `GCMRegistrar.isRegistered()` returns false while `GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId()` returns the real id!!! Why is that?
and the most interesting part is that `GCMRegistrar.isRegistered()` started to return true ONLY AFTER app registered the regId on 3rd party server, particularly after execution of:

```
GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true);
```

Yeah, right... I would uderstand this if I were talking about `GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer()` method BUT I'm talking about `GCMRegistrar.isRegistered()`. So I cant uderstand the way it acts and moreover which way to check should I use - `GCMRegistrar.isRegistered()` OR `TextUtils.isEmpty(GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId())`?

Comment: "Now with this in mind WHY didn't they use this method but they made a check if RegistrationId is empty? " -- according to your code snippet, they do use that method and do not check if the registration ID is empty.

Comment: I think your have the code snippets switched around

Comment: You are right. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source code of GCMRegistrar](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.java?r=87275a7eaab265c60b17f178b0c5cdd2983dc686), you'll see that using `isRegistered` is identical to checking the value returned by `getRegistrationId`.

```
/**
 * Checks whether the application was successfully registered on GCM
 * service.
 */
public static boolean isRegistered(Context context) {
    return getRegistrationId(context).length() > 0;
}
```

Anyway, this class is deprecated, and you should take a look at the new version of [Google's Demo App](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/#demo%2Fapp).

Comment: If so then WHY does it return false while getRegistrationId() returns valid id? I mentioned this fact in my question. Maybe the src code is outdated?

Comment: And about new version of Google's Demo App. Somehow it doesn't included in SDK but the code I mentioned in my question does. Also the new version of GCM requires GPS which will be downloaded only for purpose of GCM which is not acceptable as for me. Im not developing the game why should I make users to download and install Google Play Services? Does it make any sence?

Comment: @Stan I'm not sure why you experience the different behavior. Perhaps you have a different version of GCMRegistrar.

Comment: @Stan The code you mentioned in your question is included in the now deprecated client library. Google Play Services, even though it contains the word "Play" is not for games only (in the same way the Play Store app contains apps that are not only games). It's the new API that Google support, and therefore it's expected to have less bugs over time than the deprecated registration method used by GCMRegistrar. You can safely assume that your app won't be the only app using GCM on most devices, so Google Play Services will probably already be installed on most devices.

Comment: I know that GPS is not intented only for games but sometimes its hard to explain to custumer why is that "play thing" required when its not a game is developing.

Comment: @Stan I understand, but I think that most devices will already have play services installed.